# Open GL ES: rendering a coloured texture in black and white?

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es

Is it possible to render a coloured texture in black and white using ES 1.X? If yes, how?

Comment: Are you using ES 1.x (the fixed pipeline) or 2.x (the programmable)? I'd guess the former?

Comment: @Tommy: yes the former, how did you know? And does JustSid's answer work with ES 1.x?

Comment: No, my answer doesn't work with ES 1.1. Tommy knew this probably because most OpenGL ES tutorials only cover the deprecated ES 1.1 because many people think shaders are to complex for beginner (which is btw complete garbage)

Comment: My guess was also because converting to greyscale is relatively easy in ES 2.x, but annoyingly difficult in ES 1.x, requiring you to find some way to get the value for one colour channel to be written to another...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is very convoluted — using the GL_COMBINE texEnv mode to do a per-pixel dot product, though I can't seem to find a route through that doesn't involve an intermediate FBO and reducing the precision of your RGB channels to 7 bits a piece. So you're using the dot3 functionality that's generally intended for lighting, but because you don't want to use negative values you're ending up with half the available range. You'd basically just dot product everything with the vector (0.299, 0.587, 0.114) and output that on all three channels.

Answer (score 0):

With a fragment shader that converts the color information into grayscale. Its pretty simple, just add all three channels and divide them with three (there are more advanced ways but this simple way works in most if not all cases).

Comment: The 'more advanced' way would be to calculate 0.299*r + 0.587*g + 0.114*b, which you can do in a single operation using the dot function.

Comment: @Tommy: Thanks, I forgot the actual values and thus didn't mentioned them.